# Draw texture using D3D9

Tags: c#

i want to draw bitmap using D3D9.. I got code here and it works out. It does draw me box and image, but when i draw only box i got fps around 60. When i uncomment that code for drawing bitmap i got fps between 5-30 and it's very lagging. What's wrong with my code ?

```
private void D3D9Render()
{
    do
    {
        Drawing.Device.Clear(D3D9.ClearFlags.Target, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
        Drawing.Device.BeginScene();
        Drawing.DrawText("Fps : " + Fps.CalculateFrameRate().ToString(), Drawing.Width - 72, 220, Color.White);

        Drawing.DrawBox(v.X, v.Y, 90, 7);
    /*
            Drawing.DrawTexture(new Bitmap("test.jpg"));
            Drawing.Sprite.Begin(D3D9.SpriteFlags.None);
            Drawing.Sprite.Draw(Drawing.Texture, Drawing.TextureSize,
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(v.X-65, v.Y-55, v.Z), Color.White);
            Drawing.Sprite.End();
    */
        Drawing.Device.EndScene();
        Drawing.Device.Present();

    } while (true);

}


public static void DrawTexture(Bitmap image)
{
    Texture = new Texture(Device, image, Usage.None, Pool.Managed);

    using (Surface surface = Texture.GetSurfaceLevel(0))
    {
        SurfaceDescription surfaceDescription = surface.Description;
        TextureSize = new Rectangle(0, 0,
                          surfaceDescription.Width,
                          surfaceDescription.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not read a texture from a file each frame. Do it once before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried allocating your bitmap outside of your render loop? Depending on the size of the bitmap, it could really slow things down. You're allocating and re-allocating space for that bitmap each iteration of the loop.

Move its allocation outside of the loop and then render it (that one allocation) in your render loop.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, i put `Drawing.DrawTexture(new Bitmap("test.jpg"));` out of loop and i have again fps around 60. Wondering why i didnt find that out by myself. I guess that's not good idea do coding at 3 o clock in the morning.